# Limit Attemps with Memory Match game

Tags: javascript

I Have this memory match game code and trying to figure out how to limit the number of attempts to 6. Can you please help and point me in the right direction?

```
(function() {
    var Memory = {
        init: function(cards) {
            this.$game = $(".game");
            this.$modal = $(".modal");
            this.$overlay = $(".modal-overlay");
            this.$restartButton = $("button.restart");
            this.cardsArray = $.merge(cards, cards);
            this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
            this.setup();
        },
        shuffleCards: function(cardsArray) {
            this.$cards = $(this.shuffle(this.cardsArray));
        },
        setup: function() {
            this.html = this.buildHTML();
            this.$game.html(this.html);
            this.$memoryCards = $(".card");
            this.binding();
            this.paused = false;
            this.guess = null;
        },
        binding: function() {
            this.$memoryCards.on("click", this.cardClicked);
            this.$restartButton.on("click", $.proxy(this.reset, this));
        },
        // kinda messy but hey
        cardClicked: function() {
            var _ = Memory;
            var $card = $(this);
            if (!_.paused && !$card.find(".inside").hasClass("matched") && !$card.find(".inside").hasClass("picked")) {
                $card.find(".inside").addClass("picked");
                if (!_.guess) {
                    _.guess = $(this).attr("data-id");
                } else if (_.guess == $(this).attr("data-id") && !$(this).hasClass("picked")) {
                    $(".picked").addClass("matched");
                    _.guess = null;
                } else {
                    _.guess = null;
                    _.paused = true;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".picked").removeClass("picked");
                        Memory.paused = false;
                    }, 600);
                }
                if ($(".matched").length == $(".card").length) {
                    _.win();
                }
            }
        },
        win: function() {
            this.paused = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                Memory.showModal();
                Memory.$game.fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
        },
        showModal: function() {
            this.$overlay.show();
            this.$modal.fadeIn("slow");
        },
        hideModal: function() {
            this.$overlay.hide();
            this.$modal.hide();
        },
        reset: function() {
            this.hideModal();
            this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
            this.setup();
            this.$game.show("slow");
        },
        // Testing Algorithm -- Hopefully I got this right.. 
        shuffle: function(array) {
            var counter = array.length,
                temp, index;
            // While there are elements in the array
            while (counter > 0) {
                // Pick a random index
                index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
                // Decrease counter by 1
                counter--;
                // And swap the last element with it
                temp = array[counter];
                array[counter] = array[index];
                array[index] = temp;
            }
            return array;
        },
        buildHTML: function() {
            var frag = '';
            this.$cards.each(function(k, v) {
                frag += '<div class="card" data-id="' + v.id + '"><div class="inside">\
            <div class="front"><img src="' + v.img + '"\
            alt="' + v.name + '" /></div>\
            <div class="back"><img src="http://media.chevrolet.com/content/Pages/promo_tiles/us/chevrolet/news/home/_jcr_content/image1.img.resize.maxw_340.maxh_180.jpg/1442886815536.jpg"\
            alt="Chevy LOGO" /></div></div>\
            </div>';
            });
            return frag;
        }
    };
    var cards = [{
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Silverado 2500HD",
        opacity: "0.5",
        img: "https://cms.kelleybluebookimages.com/content/dam/kbb-editorial/make/chevrolet/silverado-hd/2017/01-2017-chevrolet-silverado-2500hd-duramax.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.web.1280.1280.jpeg",
        id: 1,
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Suburban",
        img: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZrYuZloKXYw/maxresdefault.jpg",
        id: 2
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Sonic",
        img: "http://media.chevrolet.com/content/dam/Media/images/US/Vehicles/Chevrolet/Cars/Sonic/2017/Product/2017-Chevrolet-Sonic-005.jpg",
        id: 3
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Volt",
        img: "http://images.techtimes.com/data/images/full/254611/2017-chevrolet-volt.jpg",
        id: 4
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevy ss",
        img: "http://images.hgmsites.net/lrg/2016-chevrolet-ss_100527985_l.jpg",
        id: 5
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevy Tahoe",
        img: "https://carsintrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/2017-Chevrolet-Tahoe-front.jpg",
        id: 6
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Trax",
        img: "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--tNBjBsw7--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/kd4i058ck1jvs7vr9hfp.png",
        id: 7
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Spark",
        img: "http://robbinschevy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2017-chevy-spark-blog_o.jpg",
        id: 8
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Malibu",
        img: "https://carsintrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/2017-chevrolet-malibu-pictures-1.jpg",
        id: 9
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevrolet Impala",
        img: "https://carsintrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/2017-Chevrolet-Impala-release-2-1.jpg",
        id: 10
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevy Cruze",
        img: "https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com/chevrolet/cruze/2017/oem/2017_chevrolet_cruze_4dr-hatchback_premier_fq_oem_1_400.jpg",
        id: 11
    }, {
        name: "2017 Chevy Camaro",
        img: "http://www.chevrolet.com/content/dam/Chevrolet/northamerica/usa/nscwebsite/en/Home/Vehicles/Performance/2017_Camaro/Model_Overview/01_images/2017-chevrolet-camaro-six-mo-masthead-1480x551-01.jpg",
        id: 12
    }, ];
    Memory.init(cards);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to count guesses to your game (initialized to 0 when a game starts); check it before any guess is attempted; if a guess is wrong, add 1 to that counter.